# 500 Response Body is Unreadable

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I am in the process of moving one of my sites to a new server.  On the new server I am receiving the following response for one of my pages which works fine on the old server:
[image: Unreadable Error]

I assume that something about that page did not like being moved to a new server, and I can certainly figure of how to fix that, but I do not know how to read this error message to know where to look for my error.

Comment: Is there some kind of compression being performed in IIS on the original server?

Comment: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats